# if-then statement using VBscript not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript, if-statement

I'm trying to reclass from the value of field using if then statement.
the statement is like this..

[image]

In the figure above, what is making the result not work on my ArcGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code and error messages we ask that you show us them in full using text rather than a picture so that they can be searched and also read easily on all devices.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`"`** button for quoting errors and a **`{}`** button button that enables you to format any highlighted text nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you have to use with if..then is like this

```
dim y
if [PR_TBS] <= 100 then
  y = "< 101 Ton" 
elseif [PR_TBS] <= 200 then
  y = "101-200 Ton"
elseif [PR_TBS] <= 300 then
  y = "201-300 Ton"
elseif [PR_TBS] <= 400 then
  y = "301-400 Ton"
else
  y = "> 400 Ton"
end if
```

You don't need to use "elseif [PR_TBS] > 100 and [PR_TBS] <= 200 then" since any value that doesn't meet the first "if" will be >100.